# How to combine a let binding and an if statment in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure, and trying to figure out the language to write things concisely and clearly. I'm trying to conditionally do something with a value after getting a value (say from a database) from a function that either returns the value or nil. I'm currently using a let binding, and then an if statement. Here is something similar to what I have currently:

```
(defn foo [key]
  (let [result (try-getting! key)]
    (if result
      (+ result 50)
      50)))
```

I'm trying to figure out if there is a more consise way to do this, perhaps some sort of combined if-let binding? Is there a way to write this better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is form [if-let](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/if-let) for this:

```
(defn foo [key]
  (if-let [result (try-getting! key)]
    (+ result 50)
    50))
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in fact `if-let` is what you want here.

```
 (if-let [result (try-getting! key)]
   (+ result 50)
   50)
```